# How to stop excel sheet from overwriting and I want it in a single sheet

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

When the data is being written (for loop) in **one singe excel sheet**, it overwrites the excel sheet and moreover to stop it from overwriting I need to separate the newer data collected to sheets.
(pandas)

So how do I do it?

Code Below:

```py
ih = input('pages: ')
def test():    
    for page in range(1, int(ih)):
        req = requests.get(url + str(page))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
        g_data = soup1.find_all('span', {"class": "b-card b-card-mod-h vehicle"})
        g_price = soup.find_all('div', {"class": "b-card--el-vehicle-price"})
        g_mile = soup.find_all('p', {"class": "b-card--el-brief-details"})
        g_name = soup.find_all('p', {"class": "b-card--el-description"})
        g_user = soup.find_all('a', {"class": "b-card--el-agency-title"})
        g_link = soup.find_all('div', {"class": "b-card--el-inner-wrapper"})
        m_price = [item.text for item in g_price]
        m_mile = [item.text for item in g_mile]
        m_user = [item.text for item in g_user]
        m_name = [item.text for item in g_name]
        m_link = [item.a["href"] for item in g_link]
        m_extensions = [('') for item in g_link]
        l1 = m_name
        l2 = m_mile
        l3 = m_price
        l4 = m_user
        l5 = m_link
        l6 = m_extensions
        s1 = pd.Series(l1, name='Vehicle Name')
        s2 = pd.Series(l2, name='Mileage')
        s3 = pd.Series(l3, name='Price')
        s4 = pd.Series(l4, name='User')
        s5 = pd.Series(l5, name='Link')
        s6 = pd.Series(l6, name='Site')
        df = pd.concat([s1,s2,s3,s4,s6+s5], axis=1)
        if(os.path.isfile('hello_world.xlsx')):
            sheet.write(df)
            workbook.close()
        else:
            sheet.write('hello_world.xlsx', index= False)
            workbook.close()
        print(f'[+]Writing Data from page ' + str(page))
        ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTitleW('[+]Writing Data from page ' + str(page))
    print('[=]Written Data')
# Write the data.
test()
```

**If anyone could help, Thanks!**

Comment: share with us the code used to save your data in excel

Comment: ok Ill share them

Comment: ive added the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use openpyxl to get the last row of the worksheet, then use the dataframe `to_excel` method to write data to a specific row. Note that you must set `writer.sheets` to prevent the workbook from being cleared before saving.

Add this method to your code:

```
def AppendExcel(df, filename):
    import openpyxl
    sheetname = "Sheet1"
    if not os.path.isfile(filename):  # create new file
        df.to_excel(filename, startrow=0, index=False, sheet_name=sheetname) 
    else:  # append
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='openpyxl') 
        writer.book = wb
        writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in wb.worksheets) # need this to prevent overwrite
        lastrow = wb[sheetname].max_row
        df.to_excel(writer, startrow=lastrow, index=False, header=False, sheet_name=sheetname) 
        writer.save()
```

With this:

```
AppendExcel(df, 'hello_world.xlsx')
```

This code is not tested, so you may have to tweak it some.

Comment: Ill check it out!

Comment: Looks like `to_excel()` clears the workbook before saving. I updated the answer to get around this.

Comment: Ill check it out!